# Copy directory from path into current directory

Tags: python, directory, copy

The following python code takes a list of file paths to a particular instance of a file to copy them into the current directory with the path name in the title:

```
python3 find.py --copy zz /Users/apt/testdir a.txt 
/Users/apt/testdir/d1/a.txt 
/Users/apt/testdir/d1/d3/a.txt 
/Users/apt/testdir/d1/d3/d4/a.txt 
/Users/apt/testdir/d1/d3/d5/a.txt
$ ls zz
Users_apt_testdir_d1_a.txt     
Users_apt_testdir_d1_d3_d4_a.txt
Users_apt_testdir_d1_d3_a.txt  
Users_apt_testdir_d1_d3_d5_a.txt
```

Everything works but my copy function:

```
def copy(f, new_dir):
   file_name=str(f[1:])
   file_name=file_name.replace('/', "_")
   file_path=os.path.join(new_dir, file_name)
   shutil.copy(file_path, new_dir)                                                                                         
   os.chdir(os.path.abspath(new_dir))
   os.rename(list(os.path.split(f))[1], file_name)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "zz/['_u_macole_testdir_d1_d3_a.txt', '_u_macole_testdir_d1_d3_d4_a.txt', '_u_macole_testdir_d1_d3_d5_a.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, either `file` or `new_dir` doesn't have the good type. Since `file` is a list, you need to iterate and call `copy` each time:
Something like

```py
def copy(f, new_dir):
   file_name=str(f[1:])
   file_name=file_name.replace('/', "_")
   file_path=os.path.join(new_dir, file_name)
   shutil.copy(file_path, new_dir)                                                                                         
   os.chdir(os.path.abspath(new_dir))
   os.rename(f, file_name)

for i in f:
   copy(i, new_dir)
```

Comment: @Matt I updated my answer after that, also I'm not sure if the leading underscore is desired, if not, you may want to put `file_name=str(f[2:])` instead of `file_name=str(f[1:])`

Comment: Does that replace the entire line?
   os.rename(list(os.path.split(f))[1], file_name)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing but os.rename take paths as parameters, not list, I update my answer with your complete code